# How to configure Aptana stuido3 for more projects in one (s)ftp connection?

Tags: ftp, aptana, aptana3

I have a server with 12 websites. Is there a way in Aptana Studio 3 to have only one sftp connection and more projects on it - with different paths, like it can be done in NetBeans? Making Extra connection for every site is not very efficient solution I think. Making one large project including every site is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you're asking for. You say you don't want separate connections for all 12, but you don't want one connection for all 12?

Answer (score 0):

If they have different paths you'll have to create individual connections for each one.  In Aptana you link a project to one or more connections, not the other way around.